# Retrieve Error Message with array

Tags: php, arrays, exception, gocardless

I have using a version of [GoCardless's API](https://gocardless.com/docs?language=php) in PHP to process payments on my website. However when their API returns an error I would like to display the user more effective errors.

I have got half way there but I was wondering if there is anyway I could do the following:

If I have the following error:

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [0] => The resource has already been confirmed ) )

Is there anyway to extract just the `The resource has already been confirmed` part with PHP?

My Code:

```
    try{
        $confirmed_resource = GoCardless::confirm_resource($confirm_params);
    }catch(GoCardless_ApiException $e){
        $err = 1;
        print '<h2>Payment Error</h2>
        <p>Server Returned : <code>' . $e->getMessage() . '</code></p>';
    }
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

Code that triggers the exception:

```
$http_response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_response_code < 200 || $http_response_code > 300) {

  // Create a string
  $message = print_r(json_decode($result, true), true);

  // Throw an exception with the error message
  throw new GoCardless_ApiException($message, $http_response_code);

}
```

**UPDATE 2 :-> `print_r($e->getMessage())` Output:**

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [0] => The resource has already been confirmed ) )

Comment: `$errorArray['error'][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem, the output from `$e->getMessage()` was a plain string, NOT an array.

So I edited the Request.php file to the following:

```
$http_response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_response_code < 200 || $http_response_code > 300) {

  // Create a string <<-- THE PROBLEM -->>
  // $message = print_r(json_decode($result, true), true);

  $message_test = json_decode($result, true);

  // Throw an exception with the error message
  // OLD - throw new GoCardless_ApiException($message, $http_response_code);
  throw new GoCardless_ApiException($message_test[error][0], $http_response_code);

}
```

and then my php file :

```
try{
    $confirmed_resource = GoCardless::confirm_resource($confirm_params);
}catch(GoCardless_ApiException $e){
    $err = 1;
    $message = $e->getMessage();

    print '<h2>Payment Error</h2>
    <p>Server Returned : <code>' . $message . "</code></p>";
}
```

and the page outputs:

> Payment Error
>
> Server Returned : The resource has already been confirmed

Answer (score 1):

The method `$e->getMessage()` appears to return an array with an index 'error' wich is an array again that contains the message text. If you ask me this is **bad API design**

However you can access the message text like this:

```
try{
    $confirmed_resource = GoCardless::confirm_resource($confirm_params);
}catch(GoCardless_ApiException $e){
    $err = 1;
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    $error = $message['error'];
    print '<h2>Payment Error</h2>
    <p>Server Returned : <code><' . $error[0] . "</code></p>";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. But bad on the api devs for returning an array in place of what should be a string.

Comment: Yeah! I'm currently searching for docs. Maybe I'll find an explanation for this

Comment: Even if you find an explanation its irrelevant IMO... They should have had get message return a string of all errors somehow not an array and should have made a new method to get an array of messages... Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks all I made a mistake in the question please see me edit :)

Comment: @prodigitalson Yes, I'm with you. I browsed the source code (for short) and I figured out, that `GoCardless_ApiException->getMessage()` is designed to return a string - but don't check argument types in it's constructor. So the problem must be in the code that triggers the excpetion. Hard to say where exactly without having more info.

Comment: @DavidPassmore Sorry it's a little bit unclear how your array looks (after so much updating the question). Can you just add the output of `print_r($e->getMessage());` to question? Whats the meaning of the code you posted at bottom of your question?

Comment: @hek2mgl Thats where the code triggers the exception according to server trace. thought it might help :)

Comment: Have you checked my recent update? it should work. (If I'm not blind ;)

Comment: Still returning : Payment Error
Server Returned : `A`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27290/discussion-between-david-passmore-and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the GoCardless_ApiException class code you'll see that there's a getResponse() method that you could use to access the error element of the response array...

```
$try{
    $confirmed_resource = GoCardless::confirm_resource($confirm_params);
}catch(GoCardless_ApiException $e){
    $err = 1;
    $response = $e->getResponse();

    print '<h2>Payment Error</h2>
    <p>Server Returned : <code>' . $response['error'][0] . "</code></p>";
}
```